# Append a node to a node in XML

Tags: xml, vb6, msxml, appendchild

I am trying to understand MSXML and its use. I have a project where i need to read a node and all of its contents from an xml file and then copy that node to another xml files. I am stuck on appending the child node. I think i am doing things correctly but i keep getting the error "Object doesnt support this property or method".

It hangs up on "xNode2.appendChild(xElement)"

I have attached the procedure i am working on.

If anyone can give me some direction it would be much appreciated.

```
Dim xDoc As DOMDocument60, xDoc2 As DOMDocument60, xNode As IXMLDOMElement, _
    xmlStr As String, xSub As IXMLDOMNode, xNode2 As IXMLDOMElement

Set xDoc = New DOMDocument60

'Attempt to load the backup file for the selected printer.
If xDoc.Load("C:\Program Files\ID Technology\CiControl\Backup Files\" & _
              main.printerView.SelectedItem.Key & "\" & _
              Format(Date, "mm.dd.yy") & ".xml") Then

    'Find the message xml in the backup file.
    Set xNode = xDoc.selectSingleNode("//Messages/Message[Name='" & msgView.SelectedItem & "']")

    'Begin extracting all of the message xml.
    For Each xSub In xNode.childNodes            
        Debug.Print xSub.xml
        'Build the xml string.
        xmlStr = xmlStr & xSub.xml
    Next

    Set xDoc2 = New DOMDocument60

    xDoc2.Load ("C:\Program Files\ID Technology\CiControl\Backup Files\127.0.0.1\" _
                & Format(Date, "mm.dd.yy") & ".xml")

    'Set xNode2 = xDoc2.createElement("Message")
    Set xNode2 = xDoc2.selectSingleNode("//Messages")

    Dim xElement As IXMLDOMElement

    Set xElement = xDoc2.createElement("Message")

    xElement.Text = xmlStr

    xNode2.appendChild (xElement)
    'xDoc2.documentElement.appendChild (xNode2)

    xDoc2.save ("C:\Program Files\ID Technology\CiControl\Backup Files\127.0.0.1\" & _
                Format(Date, "mm.dd.yy") & ".xml")

End If

Set xDoc = Nothing
Set xNode = Nothing
Set xSub = Nothing
Set xDoc2 = Nothing
Set xNode2 = Nothing
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Can you point out the exact line of code that is receiving the error?

Comment: I am receiving the error on: xNode2.appendChild (xElement)
Where am i going wrong.

Comment: @user2962310 Have you got any fix for the issue? I'm facing almost the same problem..

Answer (score 0):

You need to [import](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms767525%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) the node from the original DOM to the new DOM before you can add the node to the new DOM.

```
Dim CloneNode As IXMLDOMNode
Set CloneNode = xDoc2.ImportNode(xElement)
xNode2.appendChild (CloneNode)
```